# How do I expire home page cache when an article is updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached, activeadmin, sweeper

I'm attempting to use a sweeper to clear the home page index action when a new article is published.

The home page cache is working fine in development environment and expires after 1 minute. However when an article is saved, the sweeper action is not triggered.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  caches_action :index, :expires_in => 1.minute
  cache_sweeper :article_sweeper
  def index
    @articles = Article.published.limit(5)
  end
end

class ArticleSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Article
  def after_update(article)
    expire_action(:controller => 'home', :action => 'index')
  end
end
```

Either I've gone wrong somewhere or a different approach is needed to expire the home page cache.

My app uses ActiveAdmin to update articles, and Dalli for Memcache (as I'll be using Heroku).

Comment: how is the configuration for your production dalli store?

Comment: Did you register your observer?

Comment: @phoet - I'm only in development at this stage.

Comment: @apneadiving - Can't see that in the Railsguides sweepers doc, I have now tried adding this to application.rb though but doesn't appear to have made a difference: 
config.active_record.observers = :articles_sweeper
I could be doing it wrong though. Edit: tried both articles_sweeper and article_sweeper naming across all files.

Comment: so you have the memcache setup for your local development?

Comment: @phoet - yes, I followed the Heroku doc for this. brew install memcached and in development.rb: config.cache_store = :dalli_store in development.rb and memcached -vv to run daemon locally. Not sure the after_update is getting triggered at all though, so could be a more fundamental issue.

Comment: @Ben: sorry, I wrote too fast, only observers need to be registered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two steps to the solution:

The controller performing the changes on the model needs to have the sweeper reference, not the destination controller as shown above. In this case it is active_admin, so I added this to my admin/articles.rb file ([source](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/530)) instead of the home controller.

```
controller do
  cache_sweeper :article_sweeper
end
```

And the controller name needs a slash

```
expire_action(:controller => '/home', :action => 'index')
```

Comment: That note about the controller needing a slash is very important/useful. Been chasing my tail on this one for an hour! Thanks for sharing.